# SwiftUI: Transparent NavBar in 3 Column Layout on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a 3 column layout and for some reason, the navigation bar in the middle column starts off buggy on the initial launch of the app, ie transparent and unresponsive. I have to navigate away and back in order for the navigation bar to function properly. This only happens when I run it on the iPhone simulator, iPad works fine.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar()
            MainView()
            Text("Select mail to read")
        }
    }
}

struct Sidebar: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Browse")
            ) {
                NavigationLink(destination: MainView()) {
                    Text("Inbox")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: SentView()) {
                    Text("Sent")
                }
            }

        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .navigationTitle("Mailboxes")
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.isFetching {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(item: "\(i)"),
                            label: {
                                Text("Inbox \(i)")
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Inbox")
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct SentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(item: "\(i)"),
                    label: {
                        Text("Sent \(i)")
                    })
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Sent")
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isFetching = false
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        isFetching = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            self.isFetching = false
        }
    }
}
```

When running on iPhone:

[image]

When running on iPad:

[image]

EDIT:
Replaced code and gif with a more generic implementation for brevity.

Comment: Why are you using the ZStack?

Comment: @mahan I have a bannerAdView, which I omitted from above for brevity.

Comment: I removed all of your custom codes and used a list with forEach in CircularsListView instead of the Group. It worked as expected. I run iOS 14.5.

Comment: @mahan I have tried that and am aware that it works. However, my use case requires a Group.

Comment: It is hard to replicate the issue. Could you add all of your code? Or remove those (CircularsListViewModel, CircularRowView, etc )that you have not added?